# Error when trying to insert images into JButton using Java

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I'm trying to create a JButton because I want to insert an image into that. So I've created this code which doesn't show syntax errors but when I try to execute this exception appears:

[image]

Can someone show me how to insert this image into that JButton? Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Background extends JFrame {
 private Random ran;
 private int value;
 private JButton b;
 private JButton c;

 public Background() {

  super("ttile");
  ran = new Random();
  value = nextValue();

  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  b = new JButton("ROLL THE DICES");
  b.setForeground(Color.WHITE); //ndryshon ngjyren e shkrimit
  b.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  // b.setBounds(100, 100, 20, 70);
  add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  Icon e = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("x.png"));
  c = new JButton("hey", e);
  add(c);

  thehandler hand = new thehandler(); //konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
  b.addActionListener(hand);
  c.addActionListener(hand);

 }
 private class thehandler implements ActionListener {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Background d = new Background();

  d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
  d.setSize(3000, 3000);

  d.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the location of your `x.png` image?

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\leksione\JAVA\eclipse\Detyra e kursit\bin

Comment: It can be that the file is not located where you are pointing to, that you are not being case-sensitive, that you didn't add the file location to the build path etc. I suggest you search for the many questions on this site about loading a resource with `getresource`. It would also help if you show the structure hierarchy of where the class the and file is.

Comment: @ user1803551 Thanks a lot.It was that the class and the image paths not matching.

Comment: Can you please tell why this doesn't change the position of the button  add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH)?

Comment: Ask a new question. And don't put a space between @ and the user's name.

Comment: Where is `x.png` actually stored?  What IDE are you using?

Comment: Thanks I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace points us to the place where ImageIcon is being instantiated in the code.

```
Icon e=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("x.png"));
```

It can be fixed by correctly addressing the resource that is being loaded. If the x.png is residing in the resources folder, this will fix the problem.

```
 Icon e=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/x.png"));
```

Comment: Does'nt help this solution.

Comment: can you describe the structure of your project and the path where the resource file x.png is located ? are you using maven for build and packaging ?

Comment: C:\Users\user\Desktop\leksione\JAVA\eclipse\Detyra e kursit\bin this is the path.I'm using packagigng

Comment: Can you please tell why this doesn't change the position of the button add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH)?

Answer (score 0):

For sure try this

```
BufferedImage bim=null;
    try {
     bim=ImageIO.read(new File("c:/.../x.png"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }      
Icon e=new ImageIcon(bim);
```

with import javax.imageio.*;

in your imports

Comment: This requires the file to be within the `C:/` drive

Comment: where to insert this?

Comment: in place of Icon e = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("x.png"));

Comment: In the 3-rd  line it says:"Invalide escape sequence(valid ones are \b\t\..etc)".     "C:\Users\user\Desktop\leksione\JAVA\eclipse\Detyra e kursit\bin"  This is the path I specified

Comment: are you in windows? or mac?

Comment: on windows use the / instead of \

Comment: In windows.Tried but doecn't help.Now says buffered image cannot be resolvet to a type and file cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: you have to have the exact file "C:/Users/user/Desktop/leksione/JAVA/eclipse/Detyra e kursit/bin/x.png"

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell why this doesn't change the position of the button add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH)?

Comment: you need to have a BorderLayout

Comment: Sorry for extended discussion.I tried this but it still doesn't work  r=new JButton("ROLL THE DICES");
   r.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//ndryshon ngjyren e shkrimit
   r.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
  // b.setBounds(100, 100, 20, 70);
   Panel p2 = new Panel();
      p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      p2.add(r,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Comment: ok you need to start a new question - I dont know where this panel goes etc

Comment: Absolute paths and the absolute worst idea